# Return from linq query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, service, model

How return linq query below this

```cs
public SewaPeralatan FindByNotaSewa(string notaSewa)
{
    var dataSewa = 
        from sp in _context.SewaPeralatan
        join spd in _context.SewaPeralatanDetails on sp.Id equals spd.SpId
        where sp.NotaSewa == notaSewa
        select new { sp, spd };
                           
    return dataSewa.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

the return get error like this

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: SYN.Models.SewaPeralatan sp, SYN.Models.SewaPeralatanDetail spd>' to 'SYN.Models.SewaPeralatan'"
```

What I expect from the return is to be able to get data from the SewaPeralatanDetail table
The SewaPeralatanDetail table contains details from the SewaPeralatan Table

Comment: Then SewaPeralatan would be the wrong return type, or?

Comment: You return a ```new { sp, spd };``` but you should return a ```SewaPeralatan ```

Comment: what if you change the method to `public dynamic FindByNotaSewa(string notaSewa)`?

Comment: It's clear that `SewaPeralatan` should have a navigation property `SewaPeralatanDetails`, so you can return a `SewaPeralatan` object having the details attached and the query will reduce to a simple query with `Include`.

Comment: Yes the code working with `Include` @GertArnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using EF you can use linq like this to return `SewaParlatan`

```
 public SewaPeralatan FindByNotaSewa(string notaSewa)
        {
            var dataSewa =
                _context.SewaPeralatan
                .Where(b => b.NotaSewa == notaSewa)
                .Include(b => b.SewaPeralatanDetails)
                .FirstOrDefault();
                

            return dataSewa;
        }
```